# preprocessor for .gitignore file (used by git) for RegEx support and more

Tags: git, regex, autohotkey

After a lengthy search without results, I plan to create a preprocessor for the ".gitignore" file.

1. .gitignore does not support regEx, but glob. I would like to be able to use regEx, or both (**regEx and glob**).
2. .gitignore supports for a whitelist for a subFolder (including files) `!subFolder/**` two lines (`!subFolder` and `!subFolder/**`). I want to use only **`!SubFolder/`**, which is easy to understand.

Therfore i think it's time to start writing a little preprocessor for gitignore files. Any help is welcome!

Which language should I use for this? I started with the script language - Autohotkey and node.js. Is there perhaps a similar preprocessor somewhere? With Autohotkey I find it currently easier and faster to create. Node.js may be more useful in the long term. I also tried using Kotline to generate NodeJS-Script (but unfortunately got error messages). Tried start with this example: [hello_node.zip 94 (188 KB)](https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/business5/uploads/kotlinlang/original/1X/11fc6b6ff8d84f36346af7c19c3ac0b82075a4f6.zip)

#### Prototypes:

index.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('fs')
try {
  const data = fs.readFileSync('.gitignore', 'utf8')
  var newString = data.replace(/\n(\!(\w+)\/\*\*)[\r\n]/g, '\n!$2\n$1\n');
  console.log(newString)
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "snippet",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": {
   "gitignore": "./index.js"
 }
}
```

Autohotkey (works only in WinOS):

```
#SingleInstance,Force
Loop,9999
{
    FileReadLine, thisLine , .gitignore, %A_Index%
    if ErrorLevel
        break

    newString .= RegExReplace(thisLine,"^(\!(\w+)\/\*\*)$", "!$2`n$1") "`n"
}
MsgBox, '%newString%' = newString `n`n (line:%A_LineNumber%) `n`n`n The end of the file has been reached or there was a problem
Reload
```

Comment: I'd caution against this. Regular expressions are vastly more powerful than shell globs. Many straightforward expressions simply cannot be phrased as a shell glob. Some can, but will need to be expanded from one regular expression to millions of alternative shell globs, each of which would need to be stored.

Comment: yes it can not be the target, all regex phrased as a shell glob. yes, its not possible. but an approximation, a good compromise was possible as AHK script variant (released on githup). Useful only for the few that I can express in regEx in one line, but with Glob requires several. Shorter, more manageable, easier to edit. Of course, you can continue to simply write glob in it. These can be distinguished quite well. For example, a simple rule: no contain `\\`, then it's glob (I almost did it that way).

Comment: How's the project going?

Comment: It's on github and needs Autohotkey

Comment: github sl5net / gitignore_preprocessor